# HERE map is Overlap my Material App in Flutter

Tags: flutter, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

```
    body: GetBuilder<InitialScreenController>(
        builder: (logic) => SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 90.w,
                      width: 70.h,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,),
                    ),
                    logic.getCurrentCargoModel != null
                        ? Container()
                        : Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.h),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      // height: 3.h,
                                      width: 30.h,
                                      child: TextField(
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color:Clr.black,
                                        ),
                                        controller:tsearch,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          // if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                                          //   idstatus = false;
                                          // }
                                        },
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          filled: true,
                                          fillColor: Clr.white,
                                          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                          isDense: true,
                                          prefixIcon: Image.asset(Ast.pin),
                                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Clr.textfieldborder),
                                          ),
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                          // errorText: idstatus ? iderror : null,
                                          contentPadding:
                                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                                          // hintText: Str.categoryHint,
                                          // hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          //   fontSize: 12.sp,
                                          //   fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          //   // color: Clr.hintTexClr,
                                          // ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 2.h,
                                    ),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        // var position =
                                        //     await initialScreenController.determinePosition();
                                        // print("---------->${position!.longitude.toString()}");
                                        // print("---------->${position!.latitude.toString()}");
                                        // await logic.getCurrentCargoData();
                                        // Get.to(() => InitialMapScreen(position: position));
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        "kreni",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          fixedSize: Size(10.w, 7.w),
                                          primary: Clr.mainColor),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        switch (controller!.status) {
                          case AnimationStatus.completed:
                            controller!.reverse();
                            break;
                          case AnimationStatus.dismissed:
                            controller!.forward();
                            break;
                          default:
                        }
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          height: 100.w,
                          width: 3.w,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Clr.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(0.w),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0.w))),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            Ast.menu,
                            color: Clr.darkBlack,
                          )),
                    ),
                    _drawer(context),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: please put your code as code paragraph not plain text

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This could be related due to Flutter 3, which is not yet supported. Are you using Flutter 3? If so, try to downgrade.